# C# Window Form blinks after the timer ticks

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a c# window form project on visual studio 2013 with .Net4.5 framework.
The form has a timer and some other elements.
When I click a button called button1, the form is disabled and the timer is enabled.
For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Enabled = false;
    timer.Enabled = true;

    //do some tasks
}
```

Timer's interval is set to 50 by default. When timer ticks, the form is re-enabled.
For example:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Enabled = true;
}
```

The problem is after each timer ticks (click the button), the form blinks. What should I do to prevent that?

Comment: Can you please provide us with the steps to replicate this issue on a new Winforms project?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. You can simply create a new project with only 1 button, 1 timer and their two event like describe above. Run the project and click the button, you will see it.

Comment: When the `Form.Enabled` property is set to `true`, it refreshes itself (calls `Invalidate()` and `Update()`) and all child controls that have `ControlStyles.UserPaint` set.

Comment: @Jimi I understand. But I wonder if there is a way for the form to avoid blinking unchanged parts. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @N.H.Tung: Maybe we could help you better if you tell us the **purpose of using the timer**. If you want to disable your form when performing some tasks, (My supposation because of the `//do some tasks` in your code) then it is better to do the work on a seperate thread.

Comment: @N.H.Tung - What you're seeing is all of the controls being disabled and then re-enabled in quick succession. What's the point of disabling the form for 50 milliseconds?

Comment: What procedure requires a Form disabled for 50ms? If you cannot do without it, for some reason (which you could explain, maybe there's another way), you can take a screenshot of the client area and show it in front of the Form (a PictureBox would do) until after the Form is re-enabled. It won't flicker anymore (home-made double-buffering). It's kind of weird though.

Comment: @Enigmativity. Yes. I have some tasks executed while the form is disabled. It is to stop the user from clicking buttons or changing textboxes when the tasks are performed. I can disable only some child controls that is needed to be disabled but there will be many lines of code increasing. Btw, painted buttons can't be re-painted (buttons when mouseup and mousedown have 2 different types)

Comment: @DJ I have some comments above.

Comment: @Jimi I think it is not really good but thanks. I will find some other ways.

Comment: @N.H.Tung: Sure. If you find the answer yourself, please add it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @N.H.Tung - Then the behaviour you're seeing is expected. You should let it work this way.

Comment: If you have procedures running that require you to disable the whole thing, then you probably want synchronous procedures instead of asynchronous.

Comment: @Jimi - That might cause painting issues.

Comment: @Enigmativity The current scenario is: *disable the whole Form for 50ms* and *avoid the flickering caused by it*. Disabling the whole Form (for 50ms) or letting a synchronous procedure run wouldn't make not much of a difference. BUT then, why running a Task and use a Timer concurrently, with a fixed interval, to re-enable a Form that was disable to prevent User interaction while a Task/Tasks (totally unrelated) is/are running? What is this actually accomplishing? The OP's scenario (and code: besides what already mentioned, the Timer is enabling the Form but not disabling itself) is sketchy.

Comment: @Enigmativity Since the request to provide a better description of the actual process was unanswered, I tried something different: that *suggestion* is meant to trigger a response like *nope, can't do that because... [something revealing]*. Didn't work, apparently. As it is, the question as presented, IMO, doesn't make much sense without much more details and a description of the real operations involved.

Comment: @Jimi - I'm with you 100%.